# overriding sessions controller with devise 1.0.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, overriding, controllers

I'm trying to add a line of code to my sessions#destroy action.  My inclination was to override the devise controller with one that inherits from it.  I'm pretty familiar with the devise_for syntax, but I'm getting these results from devise 1.0.7.

```
map.devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => 'facebook_cookie'}

                         new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in                                                        {:controllers=>{:sessions=>"facebook_cookie"}, :action=>"new", :controller=>"sessions"}
                             user_session POST   /users/sign_in                                                        {:controllers=>{:sessions=>"facebook_cookie"}, :action=>"create", :controller=>"sessions"}
                     destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out                                                       {:controllers=>{:sessions=>"facebook_cookie"}, :action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"}
                        new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                                         {:action=>"new", :controller=>"passwords"}


map.devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sign_out => 'facebook_cookie'}

                         new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in                                                        {:controllers=>{:sign_out=>"facebook_cookie"}, :action=>"new", :controller=>"sessions"}
                             user_session POST   /users/sign_in                                                        {:controllers=>{:sign_out=>"facebook_cookie"}, :action=>"create", :controller=>"sessions"}
                     destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out                                                       {:controllers=>{:sign_out=>"facebook_cookie"}, :action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"}
                        new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                                         {:action=>"new", :controller=>"passwords"}


map.devise_for :users, :controller => 'facebook_cookie'

                        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in                                                        {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sessions"}
                             user_session POST   /users/sign_in                                                        {:action=>"create", :controller=>"sessions"}
                     destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out                                                       {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"}
                        new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                                         {:action=>"new", :controller=>"facebook_cookie"}


map.devise_for :users, :controller => {:sessions => 'facebook_cookie'}

                         new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in                                                        {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sessions"}
                             user_session POST   /users/sign_in                                                        {:action=>"create", :controller=>"sessions"}
                     destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out                                                       {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"}
                        new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                                         {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sessionsfacebook_cookie"}
```

It seems that when I specify :controller it affects all of my devise controllers except the one I care about (I omitted the rest from the paste).  When I specify :controllers, on the other hand, it only affects the SessionsController's routes - but it adds useless parameters instead of overriding the routing.